# How to check if a user likes a page?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I want to check if the user has liked my page or not. Here, I initialise the request for a list of likes the user has...

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"])
{
    [self.facebook setAccessToken:[defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]];
    [self.facebook setExpirationDate:[defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]];
}

if (![self.facebook isSessionValid])
{
    [self.facebook authorize:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream, user_likes", nil]];
}
else
{
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/likes" andParams:nil andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];    
}
```

The code executes to requestWithGraphPath. However it never works, I get "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)".

Comment: Why are you POSTing to /me/likes?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a get request to for likes not a POST so your problem I think is here:

```
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/likes" andParams:nil andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

this needs to be:

```
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/likes" andParams:nil andHttpMethod:@"GET" andDelegate:self];
```

This will give you the full list of likes.  If you want to find a single like, however, it looks like you'll have to do an FQL query to:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+user_id%2Cobject_id%2C+post_id+FROM+like+WHERE+user_id%3Dme%28%29%20and%20object_id=<OBJECT_ID_TO_CHECK>&access_token=<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Execute this through the iOS SDK like this mentions:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6372236
and if you get anything back the user has liked it.  Let me know if this helps.  Thanks!

**Edit:** You actually can do a single query with the graph api.  It's like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/<OBJECT_ID>
```

So just plop your object id into the request:

```
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/likes/<OBJECT_ID>" andParams:nil andHttpMethod:@"GET" andDelegate:self];
```

and you should be good.