# iOS Facebook Newsfeed

Tags: ios, facebook, feed

I'm trying to get a users newsfeed JSON on iOS.

I can't find anything in the documentation and I have found other posts related to this topic but they are all outdated. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!!!

Comment: Tell us what you already tried or read about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Make an FQL call. The query you need can be found in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream), in particular:

`SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0`

Comment: Now how will I make the request?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022522/facebook-fql-multiquery-in-ios-sdk